# Searching for information about the Go language

Tags: search, go

I was trying to look for information about generic database drivers for Google's Go language, when I notice I have hard time to get any result.

`Go SQL` returns nothing related to the Go language, and `golang SQL` only returns useful results from the mailing list (and not, say, from github).

Is there any smarter way I can look for information about the go language?

One of the creator said that search engines will recognize the context of the overloaded word "go", and it'll eliminate my problem, but I say - why bother? [go issue9](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=9)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the dashboard: http://godashboard.appspot.com/project. It's the best overview of current Go related projects. Another one is http://go-lang.cat-v.org/.

mue

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't list blog articles, and it doesn't search the description of the projects. Better than nothing, though.

Comment: The Go homepage shows a link to the Go Nuts mailing list unter the menu "Communitiy". It links to the Google groups page for the mailing list which contains also a search field. Direct link ist: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts.

Comment: Btw, search with the term golang is often more useful. And there's no generic database driver for Go yet.